# The tightest prime zipper

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Define a *prime zipper* as an increasing function $f(n)$ mapping $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{N}$
with the property that, for every $n \ge 1$, there is at least one prime within the
inclusive interval $[ f(n), f(n+1) ]$.
For example, let $f(n)=2^n$. 

   
[image: PrimeZipper]

This is a prime zipper, because [Bertrand's Postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) says that, for every $n$, there is a prime $p$
such that $n < p < 2n$.

What is the slowest-growing known or conjectured prime zipper? Is there a polynomial prime zipper?

Comment: You can use results from analytic number theory to craft many such zippers.  Using f(x)= ceil(x+x^{0.525}), and letting g(n) be the nth iterate of x_0 will be one of the slowest growing provable zippers.  Alternately use f(x)=ceil(x + x/a),
where a is something like 160000, and be sure to start large
enough.  I personally think ceil(x + log(x)^2) should work with x_0 = 8.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Jacobsthal's Function" Paseman, 2012.11.09

Comment: Oh, and 2^n is indeed a zipper because of Bertrand's postulate and small cases.  It should be provable that for
any alpha > 0 there is a positive integer c such that
Ceil((1+alpha)^(c+n)) is also a zipper.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.11.09

Comment: It is conjectured, widely believed, but not proved, that there's always a prime between consecutive squares. 

Comment: You might be interested in what Scott Aaronson has to say in section 3.3 of his article, " Why Philosophers Should Care About Computational Complexity", available on the arXiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1791. In footnote 17, he points out that "the first prime larger than 2k − 1" will count as a "known prime" if the gap between n-digit primes never exceeds n^2.

Comment: @Gerry & Sam: Thanks for your remarks re squares---That's exactly the type of information that I sought.

Comment: If I understand your definition correctly, $f(n) = p_n$ is a prime zipper. Can any prime zipper grow more slowly than that?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, slightly. $f(2n) = p_n$, $f(2n+1) = \lfloor \frac{p_n + p_{n+1}}{2}\rfloor$ needs slight tweaking to account for the sole prime gap of 1, but the idea should be clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The slowest growing zipper will depend on the size of $p_{n+1}-p_n$ where $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime number.  There are many results regarding the size of the largest prime gap.

**Unconditional:**  The work of Baker, Harman and Pintz shows that $$p_{n+1}-p_n \ll p_n^{0.525}$$ for some computable constant.   This means that your zipper function may be taken to be $f(n)=Cn^{40/19}$ for some constant $C$.  The $\frac{40}{19}$ appears in the exponent because $\frac{40}{19}=\frac{1}{1-0.525}$.

**Conditional:**
If we assume the [Riemann Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis), then we have $$ p_{n+1}-p_n \ll \sqrt {p_n}\log p_n,$$ and we may take $f(n)=n^2 \log n$.  Assuming [Cramér's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture), which says that $$p_{n+1}-p_n =O\left((\log p_n)^2\right),$$ would allows us to take $f(n)=Cn(\log n)^2$ for some constant $C$.

Also see this [Wikipedia article on prime gaps.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap)

**Remark:** Note that finding a prime zipper which grows slower than $f(n)=Cn^{40/19}$ would imply better bounds on the largest prime gap, so your question is equivalent to asking what is the largest prime gap.

** Avoid pointless functions such as $f(n)=p_n+1$.

Comment: @Eric: Thank you for this informed and precise answer! Your comments make clear that my question bumps into the as-yet not-totally resolved determination of largest prime gaps.

Comment: You can decrease the constant to $1/(8\pi)$ in your first conditional proof, a result of Schoenfeld.